# How to get the value of manytomany field as a list in Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    category = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, null=True, max_length=50)
    setting = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

| id | subject_id | contact_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 66 | 13 |
| 2 | 66 | 28 |
| 3 | 71 | 13 |
| 4 | 71 | 28 |
| 5 | 98 | 13 |
| 6 | 98 | 28 |
| 7 | 98 | 37 |
| 8 | 20 | 13 |

```
Subject.objects.values('id', 'setting')

-> [{'id': 66, 'setting': [13, 28]}, {'id': 71, 'setting': [13, 28]}, {'id': 98, 'setting': [13, 28, 37]}, {'id': 20, 'setting': [13]}]
```

I was wondering how to get the value of ManyToManyField as a list in Django queryset. The queryset above is the result I want, but I get the output as below. How can I get the value of ManyToManyField into a list?

```
Subject.objects.values('id', 'setting')

-> [{'id': 66, 'setting': [13]}, {'id': 66, 'setting': [28]}, {'id': 71, 'setting': [13]}, {'id': 71, 'setting': [28]}, {'id': 98, 'setting': [13]}, {'id': 98, 'setting': [28]}, {'id': 98, 'setting': [37]}, {'id': 20, 'setting': [13]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subject1 = Subject.objects.create(subject_id=66)
contact1 = Contact.objects.create(contact_id=13)
contact2 = Contact.objects.create(contact_id=28)

subject1.setting.add(bbq_sauce)
subject1.setting.add(mayo_sauce)

print(subject1.setting.all())
```

This code returns queryset with every contact_id for one subject_id. I believe by iterating through every subject you can get all contact_ids

Website where I found this information: https://www.sankalpjonna.com/learn-django/the-right-way-to-use-a-manytomanyfield-in-django

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).